# how can i execute mongodb without connection issue on my mac?

Tags: mongodb, macos

i wrote it to download mongodb in my mac

```
$ brew tap mongodb/brew
$ brew install mongodb-community@4.4
$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

then after i type `mongod`and `mongo`, terminal showed it.

`mongod`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.881+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.884+09:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.884+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.885+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":20966,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"1111ui-MacBookPro-2.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.885+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.4","gitVersion":"8db30a63db1a9d84bdcad0c83369623f708e0397","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.885+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.3.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.885+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.886+09:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.886+09:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-24T14:39:55.886+09:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

`mongo`

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

how can i solve this issue plz help me ...!

Comment: change owner of `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file to mongod or mongodb user

Comment: When you started the Mongo service then you must not run "mongod" which is basically the same, i. e. you try to start the service twice.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar 
thx! i googled 'mongodb set on big sur' then i solved this issue!!